# Cambio en UI en C# sin el código fuente

Tags: c#

en la empresa donde trabajo requieren cambiar unos títulos de unas pestañas de un programa que según se indica está escrito en C#,el problema es que no se tiene el código fuente del programa y quería saber si hay alguna forma de poder cambiar eso, gracias!

Comment: Puedes decompilar la aplicación, normalmente si no está ofuscado el código es una operación no muy complicada. Una vez hecho, modificas lo que necesites y recompilas.

Comment: Es aplicación escritorio o web?

Comment: ¿Por qué no se tiene el código fuente, en primer lugar? Puedes intentar descompilarlo con [JetBrains decompiler](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Answer (score 0):

Si se trata de una aplicación multiidioma podrían haber fichero de recursos, que dependiendo de como se distribuya la aplicación, pueden estar visibles antes de la instalación.

No te debería costar mucho abrir esos ficheros y modificar las cadenas a tu conveniencia.

En el caso en que no se encuentren los archivos de recursos antes de la instalación, a lo mejor los puedes encontrar despúes de la instalación, generalmente en una carpeta bajo `c:\Archivos de programa` o también bajo `C:\ProgramData` (carpeta protegida del sistema)